# kohana routing not working properly

Tags: kohana, url-routing

I run with this default routing:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Now i have set up user/index and user/login, by:

```
Class Controller_User extends Controller {

        public function action_index()
        {
        #stuff
        }
        public function action_login(){
         # stuff
        }
```

Now i have another controller right now called class Controller_Restaurants. I can access this by restaurants/index, restaurants/view . I would like to access this as: user/restaurants/index, user/restaurants/view

I have this at the moment:

```
Class Controller_Restaurants extends Controller{
```

I tried with this:

```
Class Controller_User_Restaurans extends Controller{
```

But it does not work.. What have i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::set('restaurants', 'user/restaurants(/<action>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'restaurants',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

I'd advise against using the default route, and build better, more meaningful specific routes.

Comment: I get: ErrorException [ Warning ]: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 46

Comment: Yep, I missed an ending `)` char, tereško fixed it up for me.